# Webchart in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, webchartcontrol

Am working with webchart control in asp.net(http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/WebChart/) The X-axis labels are long(say 30 chars) and hence gets truncated. is there a better way of displaying them?

Thanks,
Geetha

Answer (score 0):

some of the charting components automatically change x-axis label orientation if there are many of them or some of them are long. You should also be programmatically able to set it. I had done this while using ChartFX charts.

Comment: am looking for free tools, since it is a very minor application. ChartFX has to be bought, and trial version s only avl for 30 days.. So can you suggest some other controls that you know of?

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is programatically change the bottom padding of the chart in order to change the height available to the strings on the x axis.

To change the truncation settings of the chart control using the `ChartText.StringFormat` property and instantiate it with the appropriate enum (you can turn truncation off). The Enums can be added to combine effects. instantiate a new `StringFormat` object and go from there.

If you are iterating over your data (like I am) you can add a line like

`If strXVal.Length > 15 Then objEngine.BottomChartPadding = 150`

that will programatically provide more room for your x-axis text.